# Unable to find package 'WPtoolkit'

Tags: visual-studio-2012, windows-phone-8, visual-studio-2013, nuget, wptoolkit

I want to install the Windows Phone Toolkit, following instructions from the [Codeplex](http://phone.codeplex.com/), but I keep getting the following error message in the Package Manager Console:

```
Install-Package : Unable to find package 'WPtoolkit'.
At line:1 char:1
+ Install-Package WPtoolkit
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Install-Package], InvalidOperationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NuGetCmdletUnhandledException,NuGet.PowerShell.Commands.InstallPackageCommand
```

I also tried to look in "Manage NuGet Packages" and I couldn't find the Toolkit in the online tab there either.

Context: I've tried in VS2012 and VS2013, tried building as a WP8 and WP8.1 app.

I need this Toolkit because of the view components in there like the ListPicker and LongListMultiSelector. 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you download the toolkit or manually added through the Package Manager Console?

Answer (score 3):

See if you have any updates available for Nuget Package Manager in the Notifications in the Notifications panel. If so try updating the package manager and try to re install WPToolkit.

Answer (score 3):

I somehow managed to download the WPToolkit. I don't know which step fixed it but this is what I did:

1. Opened VS2013. Before opening any project, went to Tools > Extensions and Updates.
2. Under "Installed" tab I found the NuGet Package Manager for Visual Studio 2013, and uninstalled it.
3. Went to "Online" tab and installed it again.
4. Opened up my project.
5. Went to Tools > NuGet Package Manager > Manage NuGet Packages for Solution.
6. Searched in "Online" tab for "WPtoolkit" and found it!

I don't know if this helps anyone else but it may have been a bug in VS.

Comment: Thank you. I got it by following 5 and 6 after I had opened my solution (4). Before I was going through the console and it didn't work. After copying and pasting from several sites in case it was case sensitive, etc.